# Javascript/HTML Calculator with numbers and radio buttons is not displaying output

Tags: javascript, html

I started learning Javascript/HTML today, and I'm trying to make a profit calculator for a resale app to help me keep track of my profit. The general rules are that any item under $15 has a commission fee of $2.95 and anything over $15 has a commission fee of 20%. You can also offer buyers discounts of $0 (none), $2.12 ($4.99 shipping), or $7.11 (free shipping) on the shipping fee. Everything so far is working except for the fact that when I click on the "Click to calculate" button, nothing shows up. I don't want to use alert(), because I want to keep a history tab so that I can reference back to what I previously entered in.

1. How do I make the calculator print out without using alert()?
2. How can I keep a history page/bar on the side of the calculator?

Thanks!

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Profit Calculator</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function computeProfit() {
        var sell = Number(document.getElementById('sell').value);
        var original = Number(document.getElementById('original').value);
        var ship_offer = document.getElementsByName('ship_offer').value;
        if (sell <= 15) {
          if (ship_offer[1].checked) {
            var result = (sell - 2.95 - 2.12 - original).toFixed(2);
          } else if (ship_offer[0].checked) {
            var result = (sell - 2.95 - 7.11 - original).toFixed(2);
          } else {
            var result = (sell - 2.95 - original).toFixed(2);
          }
        } else {
          if (ship_offer[1].checked) {
            var result = (sell * 0.8 - 2.12 - original).toFixed(2);
          } else if (ship_offer[0].checked) {
            var result = (sell * 0.8 - 7.11 - original).toFixed(2);
          } else {
            var result = (sell * 0.8 - original).toFixed(2);
          }
        }
        result = result.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ',');
        document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = 'Profit: $' + result;
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>Selling Price: $<input id="sell" type="number" min="3" max="10000000000" /></p>
    <p>Original Price: $<input id="original" type="number" min="0" max="10000000000" step=".01" /></p>
    <p>Shipping Discount:</p>
    <p>
      <input type="radio" name="ship_offer" />None<br />
      <input type="radio" name="ship_offer" />$4.99<br />
      <input type="radio" name="ship_offer" />Free<br />
    </p>
    <br />
    <button onclick="computeProfit()">Click to calculate</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

UPDATE:
examples->

- selling price: $13

  original price (what price the seller originally bought the item
  for): $6

  shipping discount: none (seller doesn't have to cover any shipping
  costs to buyer)

  profit: 4.05 (13-2.95-6)
- selling price: $13

  original price: $6

  shipping discount: $4.99 (original shipping cost for buyers is $7.11,
  but now it's $4.99 because the seller covers $2.12)

  profit: 1.93 (13-2.95-2.12-6)
- selling price: $13

  original price: $6

  shipping discount: free (original shipping cost for buyers is $7.11,
  but now it's free because the seller covers all $7.11)

  profit: -3.06 (13-2.95-7.11-6)
- selling price: $100

  original price: $60

  shipping discount: none

  profit: 20 (100*0.8-60)
- selling price: $100

  original price: $60

  shipping discount: $4.99

  profit: 17.88 (100*0.8-2.12-60)
- selling price: $100

  original price: $60

  shipping discount: free

  profit: 12.89 (100*0.8-7.11-60)

Comment: `ship_offer = document.getElementsByName("ship_offer").value` is an issue, since `.getElementsByName()` returns a Collection of Elements. Also, you should just have `var result` or `let result` above all of those conditions, since its extra code to write `var` every time.

Comment: @StackSlave can I do this?                                                                                         var ship_offer1 = document.getElementById("ship_offer1").value;
        var ship_offer2 = document.getElementById("ship_offer2").value;
        var ship_offer3 = document.getElementById("ship_offer3").value;                      <input id="ship_offer1" type="radio" name="ship_offer">None<br>
      <input id="ship_offer2" type="radio" name="ship_offer">$4.99<br>
      <input id="ship_offer3" type="radio" name="ship_offer">Free<br>

Comment: Sure, or just loop over the Collection, without the `.value` property, getting the `.value` at every step of the loop: `const ship_offer = document.getElementsByName('ship_offer'); for(let n of ship_offer){ if(n.checked){ /* do something with n.value (I like n for node) */ } }`

Comment: You can't `getElementsByName().value` like that. Remove the `.value()` to get the array you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Profit Calculator</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function computeProfit() {
        const sell = Number(document.getElementById('sell').value);
        const original = Number(document.getElementById('original').value);
        // ship_offer is an array and you can't directly get the value, you need to loop
        const ship_offer = document.getElementsByName('ship_offer');
        let result;
        let selectedShipOffer;

        if(!sell || !original) return document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = "One of the inputs is empty!";

        ship_offer.forEach(selected => {
            if(selected.checked) selectedShipOffer = selected.value;
        })

        if (sell <= 15) {
          if (selectedShipOffer === "4.99") {
            result = (sell - 2.95 - 2.12 - original).toFixed(2);
          } else if (selectedShipOffer === "none") {
            result = (sell - 2.95 - original).toFixed(2);
          } else {
            result = (sell - 2.95 - 7.11 - original).toFixed(2);
          }
        } else {
          if (selectedShipOffer === "4.99") {
            result = (sell * 0.8 - 2.12 - original).toFixed(2);
          } else if (selectedShipOffer === "none") {
            result = (sell * 0.8 - original).toFixed(2);
          } else {
            result = (sell * 0.8 - 7.11 - original).toFixed(2);
          }
        }
        result = result.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ',');
        document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = 'Profit: $' + result;
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>Selling Price: $<input id="sell" type="number" min="3" max="10000000000" /></p>
    <p>Original Price: $<input id="original" type="number" min="0" max="10000000000" step=".01" /></p>
    <p>Shipping Discount:</p>
    <p>
      <!-- Grabbing the radio buttons by their value, more scalable in case you want to change its position and such. -->
      <input type="radio" name="ship_offer" value="none" />None<br />
      <input type="radio" name="ship_offer" value="4.99" />$4.99<br />
      <input type="radio" name="ship_offer" value="free" />Free<br />
    </p>
    <br />
    <button onclick="computeProfit()">Click to calculate</button>
    <!-- Missing div for result -->
    <div id="result"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I fixed a bunch of stuff for you and voila, but I feel like there's something wrong with the calculation logic, and I didn't get it to be honest. Can you edit your post and give more details? Like maybe a bunch of examples?

Comment: @bluestem also, in an ideal world where this is an actual web app, you should consider handling exceptions, forcing the user to choose a shipping discount, not letting the user input a negative number, and so on.

Comment: how do you recommend going about handling exceptions? Am I supposed to do try catch errors like in Java/Python or is there an easier way in JavaScript where I can specify specific parameters and force a user to input all the values/all the feasible values?

Comment: @bluestem In JS `try...catch`'s behavior is kind of verbose to users, that's why we usually don't use it unless there's a critical error that needs to be handled otherwise it would look unclear to users when an exception occurs, say when you use `try...catch` in your case, something goes wrong, say, radio button doesn't exist, it throws the exception that you see in the console of the browser. But it your case, the radio button *does* exist so you wouldn't count it as an exception. Now when it comes to handling regular exceptions, say, when the fields are empty and the user clicks on...

Comment: @bluestem ..."Click to calculate", you basically use an if statement to check if either one of the fields is empty, by doing, say, `if(!sell || !original) return document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = "One of the input fields is missing!";`

Comment: @bluestem I will edit the code now so you could see it in action.